# React Error : (function) is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using ReactJS and I am creating a button "remove" in a method called `showData()` and appending it to a row in a table of people.
I am setting its attribute `onclick` to my method `removePerson()` implemented in the same class of the method `showData()`.

This is all good until I click on the button "remove" - then an error shows:

> ReferenceError: removePerson() is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick

This is my code:

```
showData() {

        let localStoragePersons = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("personsForms"));
        persons = localStoragePersons !== null ? localStoragePersons : [];


        let table = document.getElementById('editableTable');
        let x = table.rows.length;
        while (--x) {
            table.deleteRow(x);
        }
        let i = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < persons.length; i++) {
            let row = table.insertRow();
            let firstNameCell = row.insertCell(0);
            let lastNameCell = row.insertCell(1);
            let birthdayCell = row.insertCell(2);
            let salaryCell = row.insertCell(3);
            let choclatesCell = row.insertCell(4);
            let genderCell = row.insertCell(5);
            let workTypeCell = row.insertCell(6);
            let hobbiesCell = row.insertCell(7);
            let descriptionCell = row.insertCell(8);
            let colorCell = row.insertCell(9);


            firstNameCell.innerHTML = persons[i].firstName;
            lastNameCell.innerHTML = persons[i].lastName;
            birthdayCell.innerHTML = persons[i].birthday;
            salaryCell.innerHTML = persons[i].salary;
            choclatesCell.innerHTML = persons[i].Choclates;
            genderCell.innerHTML = persons[i].Gender;
            workTypeCell.innerHTML = persons[i].workType;
            hobbiesCell.innerHTML = persons[i].Hobbies;
            descriptionCell.innerHTML = persons[i].Description;
            colorCell.innerHTML = persons[i].favoriteColor;
            colorCell.style.backgroundColor = persons[i].favoriteColor;

            let h = persons[i].ID;


            let removeButton = document.createElement('button');
            removeButton.setAttribute('onclick', 'removePerson(' + h + ')')
            removeButton.innerHTML = 'Remove';
            row.appendChild(removeButton);
        }
    }
```

I tried to change the code

```
removeButton.setAttribute('onclick', 'removePerson(' + h + ')');
```

to

```
removeButton.onclick = this.removePerson(h);
```

but everyTime the "showData()" method runs this method "removePerson()" run also and i don't want this to happen.

```
    removePerson(ID) {
        alert(ID);
        let table = document.getElementById('editableTable');
        if (persons.length === 1) {
            table.deleteRow(1);
            persons.pop();
            localStorage.setItem("personsForms", JSON.stringify(persons));
        }

        let target;
        let i;
        for (i = 0; i < persons.length; i++) {
            if (persons[i].ID === ID) {
                target = persons[i].firstName;
                persons.splice(i, 1); break;
            }
        }

        for (i = 1; i < table.rows.length; ++i) {
            let x = table.rows[i];
            if (x.cells[0].innerHTML === target) {
                table.deleteRow(i); break;
            }
        }

        let temp = [];
        let j = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < persons.length; ++i) {
            if (persons[i] !== null) {
                temp[j++] = persons[i];
            }
        }
        persons = temp;
        localStorage.clear();
        localStorage.setItem("personsForms", JSON.stringify(persons));
        this.showData();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you set a variable to some value, the value is computed first.

Hence, when you write `removeButton.onclick = this.removePerson(h);` the right side of the equation is evaluated first.

You can wrap it with a fat-arrow function, so that the function that will be called upon user click would be the function that calls `this.removePerson(h)`. This way its value is a lambda function, and not the actual value of `this.removePerson(h)`:

```
removeButton.onclick = () => this.removePerson(h);
```

Comment: It Worked thank you, first time i try this approach i write the code like this ~~~ removeButton.onclick = () => {this.removePerson(h)}; and it did not work.

Comment: @RabihJabr That's a very common case. Good luck!

Comment: i just want to ask something else, is it possible to get elements by id from a child component in React??

Comment: Sure: `element.getElementById(childId)`